# No option for generating Integration key on Docusign Developer account

Tags: docusignapi

My Docusign Developer account not displaying Account Administration under Preference. Now how to get integration key? #docusign

Comment: Have you considered writing to Docusign support directly? Your question seems to be off-topic.

Comment: @Everv0id has the correct path for resolution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on Preferences. Then look in the list on the left side and you will see a link named API. 
On that page, there is a button called 'Get Integrator Key'

Comment: after clicking `API and Keys` link, I am not getting and **Get Integrator Key** button as like demo server. I am only can see integrator keys, but I can not add new.

Comment: Having same problem.